# QgsPalLayerSettings is not defined

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

So I'm writing some script for QGIS 1.8 and I'm unable to resolve this error.

```
from qgis.core import *
pallyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
```

The second line gives me error that **QgsPalLayerSettings is not defined**. When I do it in QGIS 2 or higher then i don't get any errors and it imports this class. Somehow I have to stick to QGIS 1.8. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Not sure, what about removing the brackets? (e.g. `from qgis.core import QgsPalLayerSettings`)

Comment: No luck so far, this also gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it was already available in 1.8, i.e. part of the API?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx yes I'm sure and here's the link to this class in API documentation of QGIS 1.8 http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html

Comment: That's the C++ API, you need to check the python one. Things have to be manually marked for the bindings to be generated.

Comment: The python bindings are generated from the C++ API. There might have been a mistake because as i said this class is present in C++ API of QGIS 2 and is accessible from python console of QGIS as well.